# While using nested for loops does the if statement wait until the loop is over before proceeding with the if statements code?

Tags: java, if-statement

When I run the code the program will not assign the value of j to the array element at [i + 1].

I don't understand what's wrong with the program but I believe the program is adding the value of j when its loop is finished to the series[i+1], I don't know why. I was expecting the program to assign the value of j to series[i+1] as soon as the 'if statement' was fulfilled.

```
final int size = 100;
int series[] = new int[size];
series[0] = 0;
series[1] = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        if(series[i] == series[i - j]){
            series[i + 1] = j;
        }else{
            series[i + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(series));
```

Actual results: `[0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 0, 19, 0, 21, 0, 23, 0,25, 0, 27, 0, 29, 0, 31, 0, 33, 0, 35, 0, 37, 0, 39, 0, 41, 0, 43, 0, 45, 0, 47, 0, 49, 0, 51, 0, 53, 0, 55, 0, 57, 0, 59, 0, 61, 0, 63, 0, 65, 0, 67, 0, 69, 0, 71, 0, 73,0, 75, 0, 77, 0, 79, 0, 81, 0, 83, 0, 85, 0, 87, 0, 89, 0, 91, 0, 93, 0, 95, 0, 97, 0]`

Expected results: `[0,0,1,0,2,0,2,2,1,6,0,5,0,2,6,...]` also known as the van eck sequence.

Comment: The `if` statement runs in the loop. You should try a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the inner loop after the first time the if condition is fulfilled i.e.

```
for(int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        if(series[i] == series[i - j]){
            series[i + 1] = j;
            break;
        }else{
            series[i + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are overwriting the correct values.